# When do I need to modify a Python __init__ file?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-import

Suppose that you create a Python package called `app`, and it contains a module called `foo`, which has a function called `say_hello` that prints out `Hello!` to the console.

Suppose that you also create a second Python package called `boss_app` that has a module `main`. The `app` and `boss_app` are in the same directory, and the directory is on the Python path. Also, the `__init__` files are all blank. The structure is:

```
app
    __init__.py
    foo.py
boss_app
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

I want to import `app` into `boss_app.main` so that I can call `app.foo.say_hello`.

I use this command:

```
import app

app.foo.say_hello()
```

and I expect to see in the console:

```
>>>> Hello!
```

Instead, the behavior I get is that `app` is imported *but* it does not have access to `foo`.

The solution I came up with was to modify `app.__init__` so that it contained the following command:

```
from .foo import *
```

Now I get the expected behavior.

Is it always necessary to make a custom `__init__` for a package if that package is going to be imported from an outside package?

Comment: If you want to specifically `import app.foo` before you can use `app.foo.say_hello()`, then it's perfectly fine to leave `__init__.py` empty. So it's really your choice how much convenience versus namespacing you want.

Comment: But in the case that I want to `import app` and have access to it's namespace, then I have to modify the `__init__` right?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: "`import app` and have access to it's namespace": that doesn't require modifying`__init__.py`: `import app` gives you its namespace and access. What you want to do in your question, however, does. But do read jonrsharpe's link, in particular secction 6.4, and take note of `__all__`.\

Comment: But `import app` does not give me access (and does not give an error). I cannot write in the code `app.foo.say_hello()`. The error I get says that `app` does not have a member `foo`. I can do a direct, absolute import and it works, i.e. `import app.foo as foo`... or `from app import foo`. I have in fact read this doc, but I'm not seeing where it address this particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying

```
import app
```

only runs `app/__init__.py` and makes everything it initializes available to be used as `app.SOMENAME`.  If you want `app.foo` module to be available, you need to say `import app.foo`.  This will load the module.  A common example of this distinction is probably `import os` vs `import os.path`.  Just because you say `import os`, you won't have the contents of `os.path` package available.

You don't have to break modules into packages, but it helps to avoid module-name collision.  It may also help to keep concepts clear in the mind of a user of these modules.

Comment: This seems like it could be the answer to my question. However, in your example, if I import `import os`, I can still do something like `os.path.exists(file_name)`. I have not looked at the associated `__init__` file. It could very well have the appropriate import statements included. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it means there is a `path` class inside of the `os` module (and there is).

Comment: So what you're saying is that a blank `__init__` will allow classes to be recognized without extra effort but not functions not associated with a class?

Comment: `__init__.py` makes a directory into a package.  Without it, you can't say `import app.foo`.  You would have to say `import foo` and make sure that app is in your import search path.

Comment: So `os` is not broken up into separate modules? I understand that the `__init__` is required to make a package. What I don't understand is why when you import the package, it doesn't automatically make everything available as when you import a single module.

Comment: There is both `os.path` class and `os.path` module.  It is as if you defined a `foo` class in `app/__init__.py` file and this `foo` has some static methods in that `foo` class.  The `app.foo` which came from `__init__.py` would be distinct from the one which can be imported as `app/foo.py` module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100624/discussion-between-trekkiebyday-and-dmitry-rubanovich).